# Extraction of coefficient from Generating Function with partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Determine the coefficient of $~x ^ {15}~$ in:

$(1+^3+^6+^9+^{12}+^{15})(1+^6+^{12})(1+^9)$

How to use the fact that the desired coefficient is the number of partitions of 15 in parts restricted to the set {3,6,9} to compute it?

Comment: If you take a partition of $15$ whose parts are restricted to $\{3,6,9\}$ and divide each part by $3$, you get a partition of $5$ with parts restricted to $\{1,2,3\}$. List all the partitions of $5$ (there are only seven of them) and count how many have all parts in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: There is a one-to-one match between the partitions of 15 constrained to the set {3,6,9} and those of 5 restricted to the {1,2,3} set?

Comment: Do casework on if you take the x^9 in the last factor or not.

Comment: Yes, to the question in your comment.

Comment: I guess there's always some work involved to answer a question of this type

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply out the second and third terms to get $$(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12}+x^{15})(1+x^6+x^9+x^{12}+x^{15}+x^{21})$$

Then observe that each subterm in wlog the first term pairs up with at most one subterm in the other term...